# Do HF (13.56MHz) RFID readers need government approval?

Tags: rfid, regulations

If I were trying to design a product and added a RFID reader in it, would that RFID reader need government approval from the country I'm selling in?

I believe UHF RFID readers need approval from each country/region that they are sold in, but what approval would an HF device need? Specifically China if it makes a difference.

Comment: If it needs approval the product will be marked. So go down the local shop that sells such devices and see what the products on the shelves have as labels.

Answer (score 1):

There are no global regulations, each country specifies their own regulations and requirements.

The standard for 13.56 MHz RFID is No.214/DIRJEN/2005. This lists:
13.567 MHz field strength 65 microvolts/meter at 10 meters
Transmission power < 10mW

[read: III. China RFID Regulatory requirements](http://siemic.com/US/COMPANY/Publications-Article/RFID_in_China-1.pdf)

Comment: [See also this discussion on Meta.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/should-we-allow-lmgtfy-links)